# Is this a concurrency?

Tags: geometry

I was exploring this configuration with [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) and came to the following problem:

> Let a square, $ABCD$, and an equilateral triangle, $EFG$, be inscribed in a circle like shown. They are symmetrical around a y-axis. Suppose $M$, $N$ are the midpoints of $BC$ and $FG$, respectively.

**Question**: can one show that $BG$, $MN$ and the perperdicular to $FG$ through $C$ are concurrent?

---

According to my calculation they are not. But Geogebra gives an accuracy of 14 decimal places, so I am not sure whether I make a mistake or not.

[image]

Comment: Can people who vote down explain why?

Comment: Do not expect explanation... How did you come with this - by accident? Is the connection from A to the "meeting" point perpendicular to the line through the midpoints?

Comment: @Moti I was exploring this configuration with Geogebra and came to this. And no, they are not perpendicular.

Comment: According to my calculation they are not. But Geogebra gives an accuracy of 14 decimal places, so I am not sure whether I make a mistake or not. I hope to be wrong!

Comment: Let $\overline{FG}$ and $\overline{MN}$ meet at $P$. Using coordinates on a unit circle (and *Mathematica* to crunch through calculations), I found that $$(C-P)\cdot(F-G) = -\frac{9 + 6 \sqrt{2} - 3 \sqrt{3} - 5 \sqrt{6}}{
 2 \left(4 + 3 \sqrt{2} - 2 \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6}\right)} = -0.00894791$$ This is close-ish to zero, but it is definitely not zero. So, $\overline{PC}$ is not perpendicular to $\overline{FG}$, which means that $P$ does not lie on the *actual* perpendicular from $C$ to $\overline{FG}$. The given lines are not concurrent.

Comment: @Blue: I'm a bit late to the party, but that looks like it should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer (and fixing a typo), as suggested.

---

Let $\overline{BG}$ and $\overline{MN}$ meet at $H$. Using coordinates on a unit circle (and *Mathematica* to crunch through calculations), I found that

$$(C−H)\cdot(F−G)=−\frac{9+6\sqrt{2}−3\sqrt{3}−5\sqrt{6}}{
2\left(4+3\sqrt{2}−2\sqrt{3}–\sqrt{6}\right)}=−0.00894791$$

This is close-ish to zero, but it is definitely not zero. So, $\overline{CH}$ is not perpendicular to $\overline{FG}$, which means that $H$ does not lie on the *actual* perpendicular from $C$ to $\overline{FG}$. The given lines are not concurrent. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

According to my sketch in geogebra, if $X$ is the intersection of $MN$ with $BG$ then the angle between $CX$ and $FG$ is $\approx 89.45844358274003^\circ$. Hence there is no concurrency.

Comment: Is this precise? I'm not sure how reliable Geogebra is...